# Get names of all changed files in log of one file

Tags: git

How do I get the names of all changed files from one commit despite specifying a single file on the command line?

For instance, if I do a `git log --name-only` on the entire repo I will get a log like this:

```
commit abc... HEAD
Author: Joseph Blow
Date:   Tue Feb 30 ...

    Very important Change

afile.c
anotherfile.c
```

But if I do this: `git log --name-only afile.c`, then I get this:

```
commit abc... HEAD
Author: Joseph Blow
Date:   Tue Feb 30 ...

    Very important Change

afile.c
```

Despite specifying a file, I want to see all files that were changed with that commit.

[edit] The sample is just one of the many commit messages in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log --name-only --full-diff afile.c`

Despite the name this will not show a full diff, but means "do consider all files, not only the specified ones".

Comment: When I do this, it shows all commits that touch `afile.c`. Isn't the request for just a single commit?

Comment: This will make it work the way the OP wants, I think: `git log --name-only --full-diff HEAD^..HEAD -- afile.c`

Comment: Well, that would more simply be `git log --name-only --full-diff -1 afile.c`, but I don't think that is what he requested, following his example command. I think he either just cut the output after the first commit, or that is the only commit touching his file. Besides that, `<commit-ish>^..<same-commit-ish>` can be abbreviated to `<commit-ish>^!`.

Answer (score 0):

In git, this can be done in two commands. After you've done the `git log` to find the sha1, you can then use `git show --name-only <sha1>` to get the names of the other files in that commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) with [git show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) to do that in one line ;)

```
git show --name-only $(git log --format=%H -- your_filename.c)
```

Git show accept a list of hash as an argument and git log with `--format=%H` generate a list of hash that involves afile.c commits, then this list is used as a input for git show.

I hope that helps :D